# How to build user-friendly interface to allow the detection of invalid input?

Tags: c, visual-studio

This is my first post, and I'm really new to programming in C language.
I would like to create a program to calculate Balance, Principal, Number of Years, Interest Rate and Compound Ratio. But I got that part done already. But I'm required to make it user friendly and detect if input is not a number and provide another change for the user to input again. I tried using for loops and while loops, but it kept looping again and again. Here is what I have for now. Help me out please. Appreciate it very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int option;
    double P, r, n, t, B;
    float n1 = 1, P1, r1, B1;
    int t1;
    int limit = 1;
    int counter = 0, result = 1;
    float temp = 0, difference = 0.1;

    printf("What would you like to do today?\n");
    printf("1) Calculate Balance\n");
    printf("2) Calculate Principal\n");
    printf("3) Calculate Interest Rate\n");
    printf("4) Calculate Compound Ratio\n");
    printf("5) Calculate Number of Years\n\n");

    printf("Choose option 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    for (int marker = 0; marker <= limit; marker++)
    {

        if (option == 1)
        {
            printf("\nEnter value of P = ");
            scanf("%lf", &P);
            printf("\nEnter value of r = ");
            scanf("%lf", &r);
            printf("\nEnter value of n = ");
            scanf("%lf", &n);
            printf("\nEnter value of t = ");
            scanf("%lf", &t);

            if (P >= 0 && P <= 0 && r >= 0 && r <= 0 && n >= 0 && n <= 0 && t >= 0 && t <= 0)
            {
                B = P * pow(1 + (r / n), n * t);
                printf("\n%.2lf\n", B);
                marker = marker + 1000;
            }

            else
            {
                marker = 0;
            }
        }

        else if (option == 2)
        {
            printf("\nEnter value of r = ");
            scanf("%lf", &r);
            printf("\nEnter value of n = ");
            scanf("%lf", &n);
            printf("\nEnter value of t = ");
            scanf("%lf", &t);
            printf("\nEnter value of B = ");
            scanf("%lf", &B);

            P = ((pow(n, (n * t)) * B) / (pow((n + r), (n * t))));
            printf("\n%.2lf\n", P);
        }

        else if (option == 3)
        {
            printf("\nEnter value of n = ");
            scanf("%lf", &n);
            printf("\nEnter value of t = ");
            scanf("%lf", &t);
            printf("\nEnter value of P = ");
            scanf("%lf", &P);
            printf("\nEnter value of B = ");
            scanf("%lf", &B);

            r = (n * (pow(B, (1 / (n * t))) - pow(P, ((1 / (n * t)))))) / pow(P, (1 / (n * t)));
            printf("\n%.3lf\n", r);
        }
        
        else if (option == 4)
        {
            printf("\nEnter value of P: ");
            scanf("%f", &P1);
            printf("\nEnter value of r: ");
            scanf("%f", &r1);
            printf("\nEnter value of t: ");
            scanf("%d", &t1);
            printf("\nEnter value of B: ");
            scanf("%f", &B1);
            while (fabs(B1 - temp) >= difference)
            {
                temp = P1 * pow((1 + r1 / n1), (n1 * t1));
                n1 += 0.005;
                counter += 1;
                if (counter > 1e6) {
                    printf("\nn can't be find\n");
                    result = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (result = 1)
            {
                printf("\nn is %.0f\n", n1);
            }
        }

        else if (option == 5)
        {
            printf("\nEnter value of n = ");
            scanf("%lf", &n);
            printf("\nEnter value of r = ");
            scanf("%lf", &r);
            printf("\nEnter value of P = ");
            scanf("%lf", &P);
            printf("\nEnter value of B = ");
            scanf("%lf", &B);

            t = ((log10(B / P) / log10(1 + r / n)) / n);
            printf("\n%.2lf\n", t);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First thing - check the *return* value of `scanf`. So it won't loop forever on invalid input.

Comment: Drop `scanf`. Use `fgets` and (perhaps) `sscanf` as it will make it much easier to handle invalid input

Answer (score 0):

Here,
First, you should take the input value as a string, in the string buffer,
Second, After that, you can iterate through all the characters and checking if they are alpha's or digits, etc. using functions such as alpha, isdigit, etc defined in <ctype.h> header.

Third, If all the characters are of type integers or simply digits including the dot since it can represent floating-point values, then use atoi() and atod() functions defined <stdlib.h> header to convert these string values to numeric values.

By doing this kind of thing, you will have more control over the input buffer.

And that's all.